# Error while running application

Tags: android

```
 08-07 11:18:38.353: D/dalvikvm(15215): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 83K, 6% free 12813K/13599K, paused 21ms
 08-07 11:18:38.363: I/dalvikvm-heap(15215): Grow heap (frag case) to 15.352MB for 2908176-byte allocation
 08-07 11:18:38.393: D/dalvikvm(15215): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 6% free 15652K/16483K, paused 12ms
 08-07 11:18:38.413: D/dalvikvm(15215): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 6% free 15652K/16483K, paused 2ms+2ms
 08-07 11:18:38.443: D/dalvikvm(15215): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 15652K/16483K, paused 15ms
 08-07 11:18:38.443: I/dalvikvm-heap(15215): Grow heap (frag case) to 20.281MB for 5169196-byte allocation
 08-07 11:18:38.463: D/dalvikvm(15215): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 4% free 20700K/21539K, paused 13ms
 08-07 11:18:38.483: D/dalvikvm(15215): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 20700K/21539K, paused 2ms+2ms
 08-07 11:18:38.543: D/AndroidRuntime(15215): Shutting down VM
 08-07 11:18:38.543: W/dalvikvm(15215): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ab2210)
 08-07 11:18:38.553: E/AndroidRuntime(15215): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 08-07 11:18:38.553: E/AndroidRuntime(15215): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.demo/com.example.demo.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
 08-07 11:18:38.553: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
 08-07 11:18:38.553: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
 08-07 11:18:38.553: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
 08-07 11:18:38.553: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
 08-07 11:18:38.553: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 08-07 11:18:38.553: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 08-07 11:18:38.553: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
 08-07 11:18:38.553: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 08-07 11:18:38.553: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 08-07 11:18:38.553: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
 08-07 11:18:38.553: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
 08-07 11:18:38.553: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 08-07 11:18:38.553: E/AndroidRuntime(15215): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
 08-07 11:18:38.553: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):   at com.example.demo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
 08-07 11:18:38.553: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
 08-07 11:18:38.553: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
 08-07 11:18:38.553: E/AndroidRuntime(15215):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
```

i can run simple graphical-layout but whe i try to add some code onclick or any other its show me these errors. i deleted api 20 from sdk manager and trying to compile in api17. HOW TO SOLVE THESE ERRORS??????

Comment: `android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button`

Comment: In `MainActivity.java` line 16 you cast an `ImageView` to `Button`. change it to the right class and it should work. So if you need more help, add the xml and the src of `MainActivity`

Comment: have you made any changes inproject like, put button instead of imageview or Change imageview to button in xml file.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this exception says that you was cast `ImageView` to `Button` .

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
```

Please change `(Button)` To `(ImageView)` at **Line No 16** in **MainActivity.java**